How do I create a column value from another row in powerBI
I have the following data



Category
ID
Current




A
123
false


A
123
false


B
123
true


A
345
false


C
345
true



I want a result like the following where the category is replaced with the value of the Category column for the ID set where Current = true.  My data will only have one current = true for the ID set.



Category
ID
Current




B
123
false


B
123
false


B
123
true


C
345
false


C
345
true



Every example I see is related to return a calculate value using numerical values.

you can try to create a
new cateogry =
MAXX (
    FILTER (
        'Table',
        'Table'[ID] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[ID] )
            && 'Table'[Current] = TRUE ()
    ),
    'Table'[Category]
)



If you don't want to add a column using DAX, you can use Power Query instead:

Duplicate original query.
Filter Duplicate Query to only show rows where Current = True.
Merge Original Query and Duplicate Query on ID.
Expand Table Columns to bring in new category.
Remove old Category and rename new category.

Original Query
let
    Source = *{Import Data}*,
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source, {"ID"}, #"Duplicate Query", {"ID"}, "Duplicate Query", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Table" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Duplicate Query", {"Category"}, {"New Category"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Table",{"Category"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"New Category", "Category"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"

Duplicate Query
let
    Source = *{Import Data}*,
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Current] = true))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"


Filter will work but you can also use CALCULATE which is probably much faster for a large set.
CALCULATE(MAX(Table[ID]), Current = EARLIER(Table[Current]), 
Category =   EARLIER(Table[Category]))

When you run a calculated column expression it operates as an iterator going row by row down the dataset.
CALCULATE will cause a context transition and try find the max over the entire column but we can limit this to the rows we are interested in with the CALCULATE filter conditions.
EARLIER plucks the value out of the prior evaluation context, which in this case is the current row context containing the values of the current row we are interested in.
